# Deleting a tag from text in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a latex file with figure tags for displaying listings of programming language codes. I'd like to remove all these tags (replace them with space character) but I can't figure it out. For example, if this is the text:

```
This is the text before the figures.

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\lstset{language=C}          % Set your language (you can change the language 
 for each code-block optionally)
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]  % Start your code-block

 for(int i=0;i++;i<10)

\end{lstlisting}
\caption{The for loop in c++}
\label{code_for}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

This is the text after the figures.
```

I'd like to change it to this:

```
 This is the text before the figures.

 This is the text after the figures.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following,

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>
- In the search field paste `\\begin{figure}\[H\].*\\end{figure}`
- keep replace with field empty
- Select *Regular expression*
- check *Matches newline*
- click *replace all*

Comment: This will delete more than wanted if there are more than 1 `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}` in the text.

Comment: change the regex to this then, `\\begin{figure}\[H\].*\\lstset.*?(\\end{figure})`

Comment: @Toto is right. Both regex delete the text between figures as well.

Comment: I changed the second regex a little bit, and it works ``\\begin{figure}\[H\].*?(\\end{figure})``. Thank you.